# How to check __builtin_ function is available on gcc

Tags: c, gcc, macros, built-in

I need to know is there a method for gcc to check presence of those awesome `__builtin_MY_DESIRED_FUNCTIONs`

For example, I'd like to use `__builtin_nan` and be sure it is available for my program and it won't fail during compilation time.

I'll be more specific: on clang there is `__has_builtin` "checker" so we can write smth like

```
#if __has_builtin(__builtin_nan)
```

But I can't find analog for gcc.

And probably I can rely just on gcc, like "Oh, I'm on gcc now, just let's assume all of those `__builtin_` are here like in example below..."

```
#if __GNUC__
double mynan = __builtin_nan("0");
#endif
```

And probably it will work, till someone put this "-fno-builtin" compilation flag.

Comment: What's wrong with [NAN](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/NAN) or [nan()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/nan)?

Comment: @Shawn nothing wrong, except it is available from c99. But As I can see I can use __builtin_nan even with "-ansi" flag

Comment: autoconf [can be used](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/autoconf-2.13/html_chapter/autoconf_5.html#SEC42) to check if a compiler has a specific feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you will have to use `__GNUC__` and `__GNUC_MINOR__` (and `__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__` if you use such gcc versions) to test for each release specific builtin function (gcc releases can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html))

For example:

```
/* __builtin_mul_overflow_p added in gcc 7.4 */
#if (__GNUC__ > 7) || \
         ((__GNUC__ == 7) && (__GNUC_MINOR__ > 3))
#define BUILTIN_MUL_OVERFLOW_EXIST
#endif

#ifdef BUILTIN_MUL_OVERFLOW_EXIST
int c = __builtin_mul_overflow_p (3, 2, 3) ? 0 : 3 * 2;
#endif
```

And there is an open bug for exactly what you are asking about, in [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66970).

Answer (score 15):

Good news! a [`__has_builtin`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/cpp/_005f_005fhas_005fbuiltin.html#g_t_005f_005fhas_005fbuiltin) was added in GCC 10 (see [change notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html)):

> The special operator __has_builtin (operand) may be used in constant
> integer contexts and in preprocessor ‘#if’ and ‘#elif’ expressions to
> test whether the symbol named by its operand is recognized as a
> built-in function by GCC in the current language and conformance mode.
> It evaluates to a constant integer with a nonzero value if the
> argument refers to such a function, and to zero otherwise. The
> operator may also be used in preprocessor ‘#if’ and ‘#elif’
> expressions. The __has_builtin operator by itself, without any operand
> or parentheses, acts as a predefined macro so that support for it can
> be tested in portable code. Thus, the recommended use of the operator
> is as follows:

```
#if defined __has_builtin
#  if __has_builtin (__builtin_object_size)
#    define builtin_object_size(ptr) __builtin_object_size (ptr, 2)
#  endif
#endif
#ifndef builtin_object_size
#  define builtin_object_size(ptr)   ((size_t)-1)
#endif
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for posting it.