# Test for GNU extension

Tags: c, gcc, complex-numbers, gcc-extensions

I want to make a macro to return the real part of a complex number (which will work with double, float and long double types). The GNU C extension `__real__` seems to fit the bill (although it is not portable unfortunately). I am trying the following:

```
#include <complex.h>
#if defined(__real__)
#define MYREAL(z) (__real__ z)
#endif
```

However it seems that the `__real__` extension is not defined as a usual macro, so the defined(`__real__`) test fails, even though it is available. Does anyone know how to test for the existence of `__real__` to make a proper macro for this?

Also, if anyone knows of a portable way to do this, I'd be interested in that solution as well.

Comment: Where does `__real__` come from? Maybe that header defines an include-once guard.

Comment: [`creal()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/creal) should handle whatever you throw at it.

Comment: It's perhaps not a dup, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54079257/1270789) says it cannot easily be done.

Comment: creal() is defined for double, there are other functions (crealf, creall) for float and long double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html):

> To test for the availability of these features in conditional compilation, check for a predefined macro `__GNUC__`, which is always defined under GCC.

Hence:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__

#define MYREAL(z) (__real__(z))

#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

> Also, if anyone knows of a portable way to do this, I'd be interested in that solution as well.

That would be the `creal()` macro in `<tgmath.h>`, which works for all complex types.